# Do I need to get an ERN for using SqlCipher in iOS?

Tags: ios, encryption, core-data, sqlcipher

I am going to include SqlCipher with coredata for encrypting sqlite database.
sqlCipher - https://github.com/project-imas/encrypted-core-data

After i did some research i got to know that, if the app uses any encryption technologies, i need to need to get an ERN (Encryption Registration approval from BIS).

Also, some people said that requirement is no longer needed after 20th of September 2016.

But still I am in doubt whether i need to get that permission or not. If anyone has faced to this situation, please share some information. Highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://discuss.zetetic.net/t/export-requirements-for-applications-using-sqlcipher/47) is our current recommendations regarding export compliance with applications using SQLCipher.